# a page with og tags,when shared, isn't showing a playable video on my Facebook page (not always!)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am having an issue with a page on my site that outputs OG tags when the Facebook crawler gets it. The OG tags point to mp4 files that reside on Amazon S3 (via cloudfront).
when the page is shared, I am seeing the thumbnail + a play icon but clicking the icon takes me to the site (og:url - via 302 when the crawler isn't recognized)

On a few instances, only when I see the post for the first time, I am able to play the video.
after a refresh it is back to the way explained above. I have refreshed the cache on Facebook's end via their debugger and also tried different URLs. 
here is the link: http://demo.bubbl.me/share/fb/clip/544a7cde1ffd55212f8a4649/253
to try different URLs change the 253 at the end to a number between 100-253

Your help is greatly appreciated.